# this с использованием addEventListener

Tags: javascript

Так `alert` работает:

```js
class Test {
    #shown;

    constructor() {
        this.#shown = 'hello';
        this.showMessage.bind(this);
    }

    showMessage() {
        alert(this.#shown);
    }
}

var test = new Test;
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <button class="element" onclick="test.showMessage();">кнопка</button>
        </div>
        <script src="test.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

А так `alert` не работает:

```js
class Test {
    #shown;

    constructor() {
        this.#shown = 'hello';
        this.showMessage.bind(this);
    }

    showMessage() {
        alert(this.#shown);
    }
}

var test = new Test;

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    let element = this.querySelector('.element');
    element.addEventListener('click', test.showMessage);
})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <button class="element">кнопка</button>
        </div>
        <script src="test.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

**Почему во втором случае alert() не страбатывает, если в обоих случаях я привязываю событие на один и тот же элемент и в обоих случаях использую bind() чтобы this всегда было в контексте класса Test?**

Comment: В обоих случаях вы просто выбрасываете результат работы bind в никуда, поэтому он тут ни на что не влияет. Ну и во втором случае теряется this, потому что addEventListener подсовывает туда свой собственный this

Comment: Потому что Js даже сами разрабы уже не понимают :DD   и тут придётся костылить в виде  `element.addEventListener('click', () => { test.showMessage() });` и пр.  .... А вообще andreymal прав

Comment: В первом случае явно вызывается метод объекта... В втором случае выполняется т.н. "заимствование" метода, потому и теряется контекст его выполнения.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Во 2м примере проблемы связаны с контекстом, в функции, используемой в `addEventListener`, это не объект `test`, а кнопка `element`, у которой нужных методов и свойств нет.

**Решить можно, например, такими 2мя способами:**

В конструкторе так привязать контекст к функции:

`this.showMessage = this.showMessage.bind(this);`

Или как в комментарии к вопросу - измените функцию на стрелочную, которая использует контекст выше:

`element.addEventListener('click', () => { test.showMessage() });`

```js
class Test {
    constructor() {
        this.shown = 'hello';
        this.showMessage = this.showMessage.bind(this);
    }

    showMessage() {
        alert(this.shown);
    }
}

var test = new Test;

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    let element = this.querySelector('.element');
    element.addEventListener('click', test.showMessage);
})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <button class="element">кнопка</button>
        </div>
        <script src="test.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```